# Pubsubhubbub doesn't send push notification any more

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, websub

In order to get notified whenever a channel has a new video I have implemented the Pubsubhubbub protocol as suggested here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

The server I have for the callbackUrl is a Node.js application and I use the "pubsubhubbub" package to bootstrap the creation and handling of any events.
But for whatever reason, the server doesn't receive any more requests. I've tried resubscribing to the YouTube channels but to no luck. Is there an expiration date after which all subscriptions are dropped so that I need to re-subscribe regularly?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, YES. Unfortunately, You need to resubscribe again and again.

As I was looking for the same answer actually, after searching a bit, I found out finally that the subscription has an expiry date. See the "Subscriber Diagnostics" section for details (screenshot from "Subscriber Diagnostics" of my subscription)

[image]